# How do you copy stomp websocket sessions to redis in spring when you are using REST API and JWT

Tags: spring-boot, redis, stomp, spring-websocket, spring-session

I am building a small websocket project and secured by JWT token mechanism and I would like to store websocket sessions in redis not local memory.

```
@Override
protected void configureStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry
            .addEndpoint("/hello")
            .addInterceptors(new HttpSessionHandshakeInterceptor() {
                @Override
                public boolean beforeHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response,
                        WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Map<String, Object> attributes) throws Exception {
                    if (request instanceof ServletServerHttpRequest) {
                        ServletServerHttpRequest servletRequest = (ServletServerHttpRequest) request;
                        HttpSession session = servletRequest.getServletRequest().getSession();
                        attributes.put("sessionId", session.getId());
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            })
            .withSockJS()
            .setSessionCookieNeeded(true);
}
```

I @EnableRedisHttpSession in my redis config and the source code above safely stores http session in redis but even though I flushed my redis database, I can still send and receive my messages to my connected clients.

My speculation is that HttpSession is different from WebSocket session. How should I "intelligently" ask spring to store and maintain websocket related sessions in redis if you are using token based authentication?

**UPDATE 1**

```
StompHeaderAccessor accessor =
                    MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class);

            List<String> tokenList = accessor.getNativeHeader("username");
            accessor.removeHeader("username");

            String username = null;
            if (tokenList != null && tokenList.size() > 0) {
                username = tokenList.get(0);
            }

            AuthenticationToken authToken = new AuthenticationToken(username);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);

            switch(accessor.getCommand()) {
                case CONNECT:
                    Principal auth = username == null ? null : authToken;
                    accessor.setUser(auth);

                    return MessageBuilder.createMessage(message.getPayload(), accessor.getMessageHeaders());
                case CONNECTED:
                    System.out.println("Stomp connected");
                    break;
                case DISCONNECT:
                    System.out.println("Stomp disconnected");
                    break;
                case SEND:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return message;
```

**UPDATE 2**

I think Websocket over STOMP relies on SimpSessionId not HttpSession created during the Handshake Interceptor.

```
StompHeaderAccessor [headers={simpMessageType=MESSAGE, stompCommand=SEND, nativeHeaders={username=[*******], destination=[/app/feed], content-length=[81]}, simpSessionAttributes={SPRING.SESSION.ID=187912de-a875-45ef-995a-7723fd8715c8}, simpHeartbeat=[J@6e9173e4, simpUser=***.AuthenticationToken@1767840c: Principal: *******; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Not granted any authorities, simpSessionId=d686qam8, simpDestination=/app/feed}]
```

**UPDATE 3**

[SimpUserRegistry](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/simp/user/SimpUserRegistry.html) says this is "A registry of currently connected users." Might be this is the answer?

**UPDATE 4**

I am using RabbitMQ. Does that mean what I am doing is completely useless?

Comment: did you manage to solve it

Comment: @ShrikantHavale Not yet! Hope someone can help with it.